# UK visa refusal for Ghanaian citizen

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds, ghanaian-citizens

[image][image]

My visa was refused based on the refusal notice I have posted.

I want to know what to do and include in my next application. This is because I submitted all the necessary documents and I don't know what might have happened. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you specify what documents you submitted?

Comment: +1, I am upvoting your question and thanks for your refusal notice. It is a very standard refusal and we're preparing a CANONICAL in the background that you will enjoy. They got you dead cold on proportionality. This refusal was predictable from the very outset. You will get some good answers in due course, patience is key!

Comment: Docs include my sponsor's letter, birth certificate to show we have same parent and accompanying letter, passport copy, payslip, tenancy agreement resident permit card, and from my side I submitted letter from my employer, payslip, bank statement,leave letter, invitation from the army,birth certificate ,

Comment: That's weird, as ECO specifically notes the lack of, well, all of the above documents. Although that is not the biggest issue with the application.

Comment: @GayotFow I am sorry however I burst out laughing when I read _....you will enjoy_. On another note being a Ghanaian citizen  myself, I know a lot of young Ghanaian men apply for this British Army recruitment and are routinely refused. Even this website has several examples. I am convinced all other things aside, an application for British Army recruitment exercise is considered weak by consular officers _ab initio_ and almost always a Sisyphean undertaking because they inevitably have reduced circumstances and weak ties to Ghana. The applicants also almost always apply again and again.

Comment: Paakwadwo, as a Ghanaian myself with some knowledge and experience in this matters, I will say forget it. The chances you're going to get an approval are slim and none and Slim is out of town. You can come back later and read @Gayot Fow's canonical just to educate yourself

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so you were refused under V4.2 a, c and e of [Appendix V of Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules), so let me bring them up for reference:

> V 4.2 The applicant must satisfy the decision maker that they are a
>   genuine visitor. This means that the applicant:
>
> - (a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit; and
> - (c) is genuinely seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the visitor routes (these are listed in Appendices 3, 4 and 5); and
> - (e) must have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to their visit without working or accessing public funds.
>     This includes the cost of the return or onward journey, any costs
>     relating to dependants, and the cost of planned activities such as
>     private medical treatment.

That is a lot, and it would be easy to focus on the lesser issues and ignore the actual problem with your application - lack of proportionality between your income and how expensive will be your visit. As ECO explains in the third paragraph, you plan to spend 1,000 GBP on your visit, which represents about four times of your pre-living expenses salary. Not four months of your free cash flow, which may have been within the realm of reason, but four months of your entire salary - before paying any bills, rent or food.

From that ECO concluded that it is unreasonable to spend such amount of money to attend a job interview and that you must have some ulterior motive for your visit to the UK and subsequently refused you. The other reasons for refusal were just an icing on the cake.

There is no easy solution for that type of problem. You will either have to find better employment, one that permits enough free cash every month to make that trip a reasonable expense or have some extreme circumstances that would make spending such amount of money a reasonable choice.

Comment: Ok, so from what u have written, can I reduce the amount I plan for the trip? I guess I had it all wrong on the forms about the amount planned for the trip

Comment: @Paakwadwo you could try, but I don't think that this will make a difference. I mean how low could you realistically go, 500 quid and somehow slash all the costs of the trip? That still would constitute two full months of pay. I really do not think that there is a quick solution here for you that will grant you entry.

Comment: Paul what about the 4.3 (a & b)

Comment: (b) is random icing on the cake, you can ignore it.

Comment: @Paakwadwo You're not going to the UK for a British Army recruitment any time soon. Build yourself up economically and boost your immigration profile with international trips then after a few years you can try again. Don't waste that application fee on an almost futile always expedition..

Comment: @Paakwadwo (a) is related to the issue with funds. If the ECO doesn't believe that your true motive is to come to the job interview (as it doesn't make sense to spend that much money for it), then what can that motive be? I wager that he suspected that you want to go underground once landed so he added the extra paragraphs. But that is just extra, the real problem is with the finances, and sheik gave you great advice in that regard.

Comment: Thanks but what is the ideal budget? As it gets confusing when it comes to the finances. Because I thought once you have enough money in account from employment you can spend it.

Comment: @Paakwadwo you absolutely can do anything you want with your money. But the UK immigration also must be sure that you are a genuine visitor. And as ECO pointed out, most people would not spend that much of their income to come just for a job interview. So if increasing your income is not an option, you would have to write a very convincing answer to the question:  Why this interview is so important to you that you are willing to spend such high amount of money? It would have to be one hell of an answer to swing this around.

Comment: @tymoteus Paul, my promotion is due and salary increment is on the horizon for me. But I don't intend applying anytime soon. So what I'm asking is what is the ideal budget for a week trip when it comes to interview.  So that it serves as guideline for future applications.

Comment: @Paakwadwo there is no set ideal budget, it just has to make sense with individual situation. You can read up details in the [visit guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/581550/Visitors-v5_0.pdf)

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul no need to drag this out in comments, tell the OP this question is finished and to ask a new one!